# Recognize multiple markers of same type in ARToolkit for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, artoolkit

I'm creating strategy game with ARToolkit for Unity3D and I need the functionality of recognizing multiple same-type markers - for example when I want to build 2 buildings of the same type.

According to [this forum post](http://artoolkit.org/community/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=4631&sid=92fa6889e2ab00b48d55e29197d6e2d4) it is not possible in Unity, but [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWG4nhdsySE) shows that in some way, ARToolkit can do it.

I also tried to bind some custom functions to OnMarkerFound and OnMarkerLost events but I do not even know how to implement them properly. Only reference about this functions i found in [ARToolkit wiki](https://www.artoolworks.com/support/library/index.php?title=ARToolKit_for_Unity_-_Scripting_and_low-level_API&oldid=1701) but without further description.

How would you solve my case of recongizing such markers?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an archived version of Nathan's AR Game Demo project page: [Archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140915193825/http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~nmarshak/nathanAR_site/argame.html)

He specifically discusses using duplicate markers, however I wasn't able to determine exactly how he accomplished it. Hope this gets you a little closer to an answer. I am very interested in implementing duplicate markers in my project. Please, post a solution if you make it work.